# In Hogwart's Battle, do villain cards negate rewards from defeating a villain?

Tags: harry-potter-hogwarts-battle

The scenario we had was:

- Dementor: reward is - gain 1 heart, remove 1 from location
- Fenrik: heros can not gain hearts
- Crouch: heros can not remove from location

So, if we defeat the Dementor first, is the reward essentially wasted, due to the other villains, or does the reward still apply since it is not a 'hero' triggering the effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You will not gain the heart or remove the control.**

Andrew Wolf, the game designer from USAopoly, [cleared this up over on BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1643179/barty-vs-dementor-year-34-spoilers):

> ...  if [a Villain] has an ability preventing the Heroes from doing something, they do not gain the reward from defeating another Villain.

Comment: damn, that is what we played,but was hoping we were wrong

Comment: @WayneWeibel Yeah. The later years get pretty brutal if you get a bad combination of villains.